# Cambiar imagen del cursor

Tags: javascript

Objetivo: Al pulsar los botones, espada, hacha, etc, el estilo del cursor cambie por una imagen. PD: En el código js solo hice los dos primeros inputs pero no funcionan.

## HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="DH18.js"></script>
 <link rel="StyleSheet" href="DH18.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" value="Espada" id="bespada">
 <input type="button" value="Hacha" id="bhacha">
 <input type="button" value="Lanza" id="blanza">
 <input type="button" value="Arco" id="barco">
 <input type="button" value="Magia" id="bmagia">
</body>
</html>
```

## JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar(){
  var espada=document.getElementById('bespada');
  var hacha=document.getElementById('bhacha');
  var lanza=document.getElementById('blanza');
  var arco=document.getElementById('barco');
  var magia=document.getElementById('bmagia');
  espada.addEventListener('click', mouseEspada, false);
  hacha.addEventListener('click', mouseHacha, false);
  lanza.addEventListener('click', mouseLanza, false);
  arco.addEventListener('click', mouseArco, false);
  magia.addEventListener('click', mouseMagia, false);
 }

function mouseEspada(e){
var cuerpo=document.getElementsByTagName('html');
cuerpo.style.cursor="url('ragnell.png'),auto";
}

function mouseHacha(e){
var cuerpo=document.getElementsByTagName('html');
cuerpo.style.cursor="url('hacha.png'),auto";
}
```

Comment: Igual que en la otra pregunta, tienes que poner el cursor genérico: `elemento.style.cursor = "url('tucursor.png'),auto"`

Comment: si coloco exactamente esto:                                                                               var cuerpo=document.getElementsByTagName('html');
cuerpo.style.cursor="url("hacha.png"),auto";                                                            No funciona. Si lo pongo sin comillas y con auto, tampoco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes es que `document.getElementsByTagName`, devuelve una lista de elementos con un nombre determinado, es decir, un `pseudo-array` de elementos que deberías iterar para poder modificar sus propiedades.

### Solución:

Si quieres modificar las propiedades del elemento `html`, puedes hacerlo a través de [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement).

Ejemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {
  var espada = document.getElementById('bespada');
  var hacha = document.getElementById('bhacha');
  var lanza = document.getElementById('blanza');
  var arco = document.getElementById('barco');
  var magia = document.getElementById('bmagia');
  espada.addEventListener('click', mouseEspada, false);
  hacha.addEventListener('click', mouseHacha, false);
  //lanza.addEventListener('click', mouseLanza, false);
  //arco.addEventListener('click', mouseArco, false);
  //magia.addEventListener('click', mouseMagia, false);
}

function mouseEspada(e) {
  document.documentElement.style.cursor = "url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/118/118318.png'),auto";
}

function mouseHacha(e) {
  document.documentElement.style.cursor = "url('http://icon-icons.com/icons2/37/PNG/128/smallax_peque%C3%B1a_4378.png'),auto";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Espada" id="bespada">
<input type="button" value="Hacha" id="bhacha">
<input type="button" value="Lanza" id="blanza">
<input type="button" value="Arco" id="barco">
<input type="button" value="Magia" id="bmagia">
```